# How to call a macro as a function in a search replace %s/regex/\=call-macro-as-function/gc

Tags: substitute, macro

I want to do some edits on each match during a global substitution operation.

I found this answer

```
:% s/re\(ge\)xp/\= myfunction(submatch(1))/gc.
```

But I don't have a function, just some keystrokes.

So how can I wrap a macro into myfunction to call during substitute?

Sample use: rot13(vselection) is g?, but rot13 is not a function in vim:

```
:%s,(re)(ge)(xp),\1\=rot13(submatch(2))\3,gc
```

I found a workaround by using the bash utils without using macros [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/541628/replace-a-regular-expression-within-vim-with-an-output-produced-by-a-console-com).

```
%s/m\(atm\)ul/\=substitute(':' . system('echo '.submatch(1).'|tr A-Za-z N-ZA-Mn-za-m'),'\n','','g')/gc
```

interactively changes 'matmul' to ':ngz:'

Comment: Make a function and in the function call the macro?

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest the following:

Record your keystrokes as a macro (here in the register `q`) and call:

```
:g/regex/normal @q
```

This will apply the macro on each found regex in your document.

Example of use:

Content of your file

```
function A(){}
function B(){}
function C(){}
```

Type:

```
/function<CR>           " search for function
qqg?gnq                 " in a macro, rot13 the matched `function`
:%g//normal@q<CR>       " repeat for all `function` in the file
```

See:

- `:h :g`
- `:h :normal`
- `:h g?`
- `:h gn`

Comment: How to access the current-match in the macro? For example, I want to run rot13 on the matches, thanks.

Comment: You can do a rot13 with the `g?` command. Let me expand my answer.

Answer (score 0):

With `:substitute` (especially the *replace with expression*), you get the exact match (or any submatches), and you can transform / reorder / invoke functions on that easily.

Normal mode commands (like `g?`) can directly edit text, but they usually work on lines or text covered by `{motion}`.

What you're asking for is a cross between the two. Since there is not `rot13()` built-in function, you either have to provide that yourself (and then use `:s//\=rot13(submatch(0))`), **or** relinquish the regexp matching of `:s` and use `:global` (and / or `:call search()`) in combination with `:normal! g?`.